# mysql workbench 6.3 data export SSL connection error 2026

Tags: mysql, windows, ssl

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Windows 10, and trying to export data from a MySQL database which is on the same system. As far as I can tell, although SSL is enabled, I am not attempting to connect to MySQL via SSL. However, when I select the database that I want to export and run the export, I get the following error:

```
    11:05:08 Dumping bankaccounts (all tables)
    Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\david\appdata\local\temp\tmpgzws3n.cnf"  --set-gtid-purged=OFF --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "bankaccounts"
    mysqldump: Got error: 2026: SSL connection error: socket layer receive error when trying to connect
    Operation failed with exitcode 2
    11:05:09 Export of C:\Dev\bankaccounts.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what is actually going on here? From the error message, it looks as though the data export is trying to connect via SSL. Is that the case? If so, how can I make it connect without SSL? I can't see any SSL options, when I set up the export.

All I want to do is dump the entire database into a SQL script. I'm not trying to do anything clever - just export my database.

**Update:** I turned off SSL on the server and restarted it, and the export worked. It looks as though turning on SSL means that connections will attempt to use SSL even when that is not requested. Is that correct?

Comment: Try to modify the connection in the workbench under the SSL tab -- use SSL no